# As far as I know showinputdialog returns an output of type string but it gives me an error that it cannot convert the object to a String

Tags: java

```
 String val = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
            "Search item to Edit ",
            "Warning",
            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
            null,
            new String[]{"Item name", "Item no.","Price"},
            "");
```

Error:

> incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to String

Comment: Additonal: How can I  fix this error?? Any advise would be of much help. Thank you.

Comment: You may call `toString()` on the result , but first check that it is not `null` .

Comment: Have you tryed to cast the result as a String like suggested in the swing tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#input

Comment: Improved formate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With that much parameters, the method `showInputDialog` doesn't return a String but an Object as stated in the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog(java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20javax.swing.Icon,%20java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object))

As suggested in the [Swing tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#input), you simply have to cast the result to String.

```
String val = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
        "Search item to Edit ",
        "Warning",
        JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
        null,
        new String[]{"Item name", "Item no.","Price"},
        "");
```